# Boost Python - Unbound method call

Tags: c++, python-2.7, boost-python

I'm trying to use Python embedded in C++ with Boost::python.

My embedded script are supposed to use decorator to register their methods like following:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, object_id):
        self.object_id = object_id


    @decorator('my_id_1')
    def func1(self):    
        print("{}.func1".format(self.object_id))
```

`decorator` is declared on the C++ side, defining the method the `__init__` and `__call__`. Everything works has expected, until the call of the method, which lead to SIGSEGV or SIGARBT.

Here is an example of what I would like to do in Python:

```
#CPP side
item = {}

class decorator:
    def __init__(self, _id):
        self._id = _id

    def __call__(self, func):
        item[self._id] = func #saved as PyObject* in CPP
        print func
        return func

#Script side            
class Test(CppBase):

    def __init__(self, object_id):
        CppBase.__init__(self)
        self.object_id = object_id


    @decorator('my_id_1')
    def func1(self):    
        print("{}.func1".format(self.object_id)) 


    @decorator('my_id_2')
    def func2(self):    
        print("{}.func2".format(self.object_id)) 

#CPP side
obj1 = Test("obj1")

item['my_id_1'](obj1) #The crash append here
```

To do the call, I'm using the following function: `boost::python::call<void>(my_PyObject_func, boost::ref(my_obj_instance))`

I won't put my all C++ code because I'm actually updating a working project made from the old Python C API, and the whole API is quite huge. However, if you think I forgot some significant part of it, just tell me, and I will post those parts. Furthermore, I removed a lot of simple check such as being sure that the global Python var contain my object, no python error happened or the hash contain the requested id, to make the code lighter.

Here are my C++ Object definition

```
class CppBase: public boost::python::object {
    public:
        CppBase();

        void open(std::string, boost::python::tuple arg);

        void setRoutes(const std::hash<std::string, const Route*>&);

        inline std::hash<std::string, const Route*>*const routes() const { return route; }

    private:
      std::string name;
      QHash<std::string, const Decorator*> *route;
};

class Decorator {
    public:
        Decorator(std::string identifier);

        PyObject* call(PyObject* func);

        void invoke(boost::python::object&, boost::python::tuple) const;

        static void commit(CppBase&);
    private:
        PyObject* method;

        std::string identifier;

        static std::hash<std::string, const Decorator*> routes;
};
```

Here is how I register my Python module

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(app)
{
    boost::python::class_<CppBase, boost::noncopyable>("CppApp") //I tried to remove 'noncopyable', nothing change
    ;

    boost::python::class_<Decorator, boost::noncopyable>("decorator", boost::python::init<std::string>())
        .def("__repr__", &Decorator::repr)
        .def("__call__", &Decorator::call)
    ;
}
```

Here is the implementation of `CppBase::open` that I think is the only one important to show in my class definition.

```
...
void CppBase::open(std::string id, boost::python::tuple arg /* unused so far */){
    boost::python::call<void>(route->value(id), boost::ref(*this))
}
...
```

Here is the Python script sample, running with this example:

```
class MyScriptSubClass(CppApp):

    def __init__(self, object_id):
        CppBase.__init__(self)
        self.object_id = object_id


    @decorator('my_id_1')
    def func1(self):    
        print("{}.func1".format(self.object_id))
```

Here is how I try to make everything work

```
//... Creating Python context, Executing the Script file...

boost::python::object cls(main_module.attr("MyScriptSubClass")); //Getting the classDefinition

CppBase core = boost::python::extract<CppBase>(cls()); //Instanciating the object with the previous catched definition

Decorator::commit(core); //Save all the decorator intercepted until now into the object

core.open('my_id_1'); //Calling the function matching with this id
```

I hope I made everything clear.

In advance, thank you.